# allocate controlled memory - array size in bytes

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

I want to learn how to handle memory allocation and de-allocation. My first "task" is to experience a bit.

Basically, I want to allocate 1 kB memory using the `new` operator until an exception is thrown. I'm not quite sure how to do this but I expect it would be something similar to this:

```
int main(){
unsigned int counter = 0;
try{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            int *p_array = new int[1024*i];
            cout << sizeof(p_array);
            counter++
        }
    delete[] p_array; 
}catch (std::bad_alloc& ba){
    std::cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << endl << "Allocated 1KB " << counter << " times";
}
return 0;
}
```

**Errors:**

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:24:12: error: ‘p_array’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [out_Executable] Error 1
```

Quite a simple program but still I'm stuck. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You declared and then allocated the p_array in the scope of the for loop. It does not exist outside of that so you can not free it using delete p_array outside of the for loop.

Comment: Aside from it being out of scope, I believe that you would leave the memory that did succeed dangling. When the exception is thrown it will bypass being deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something of the form (simplified)

```
{
  int * p = ...; // p only exists in this scope
}
delete p; // p doesn't exist here
```

you are declaring a `int*` and assigning it an array for each iteration of the loop. The `int*` only lives during the single iteration. The arrays themselves live until the program ends though.